# How to limit apps from writing too often and logging too much to disk?

Tags: powertop

Are there ways to keep this at a minimum or to limit it to only when necessary?

This is from `powertop`.

I suppose with Firefox there is not much that can be done unless history/cookies/cache/etc are set to never be saved.

```
The program 'firefox-bin' is writing to file 'webappsstore.sqlite' on /dev/sda6.
This prevents the disk from going to powersave mode.
```

What is this? I don't have a Web App Store addon of any kind.

```
The program 'firefox-bin' is writing to file 'cookies.sqlite' on /dev/sda6.
This prevents the disk from going to powersave mode.

The program firefox-bin' is writing to file 'places.sqlite-wal' on /dev/sda6.
This prevents the disk from going to powersave mode.
```

What about the other apps?

```
The program 'flush-8:0' is writing to file '_CACHE_003_' on /dev/sda6.
This prevents the disk from going to powersave mode.

The program 'dconf-service' is writing to file 'user.62VC1V' on /dev/sda6.
This prevents the disk from going to powersave mode.

The program 'unity-panel-ser' is writing to file 'user' on /dev/sda6.
This prevents the disk from going to powersave mode.
```

Answer (score 1):

Most disk activity in your case (except for the last two) is done by `firefox`, saving data and history in caches.

To reduce this you can

- shut down firefox when not needed
- move the profile to RAM, see for example https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Firefox_Ramdisk

Answer (score 0):

I think if the app haven't got a option for this you only can remove them on your own I would recommend a logrotate script or did I understand your question wrong? With a logrotate script you could automate this. If I am wrong please correct me.

Comment: Thanks. Logrotate, I believe, does not prevent apps from writing logs to disk. It only manages it by compressing and rotating logs after reaching a size or after a given time.

Comment: You can remove logs with logrotate also but yes it doesn't prevent from writing logs.